# Как вывести из 3 мемо по 1 рандомной строчке

Tags: delphi

Приветствую 
Нужна помощь с кодом для мемо.
Я загружаю 3 варианта вопросов(А,Б,С) и нажимаю на кнопку **3 вопроса**
и со 2 формы где у меня есть 3 мемо должно взять с каждого по 1 рандомному вопросу и перекинуть на 1 форму в мемо как это сделать не могу реализовать
Картинка 1:
[image: Картинка 1:]

Картинка 2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программа:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uk36wOShkGO4lZdMZla8OOTs9lFfbaH5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сумбурный вопрос. Если я его правильно понял, то 3 Memo на второй форме содержат в каждой строке по экзаменационному вопросу. Чтобы случайно выбрать из них по вопросу и поместить в Memo основной формы вам нужно сделать примерно следующее:

```
Randomize; // инициализируем генератор случайных чисел
with Memo1.Lines do // будем работать с Memo1 основной формы
  begin
    Clear; // очищаем Memo1 основной формы
    Add(Form2.Memo1.Lines[Random(Form2.Memo1.Lines.Count)]); // получаем случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до (количества строк -1) в Memo1 второй формы, возвращаем строку с этим номером и добавляем её в Memo1 основной формы
    Add(Form2.Memo2.Lines[Random(Form2.Memo2.Lines.Count)]); // то же самое для Memo2 второй формы
    Add(Form2.Memo3.Lines[Random(Form2.Memo3.Lines.Count)]); // то же самое для Memo3 второй формы
  end;
```

Comment: Спасибо.
Есть ещё 2 вопроса:
1)Я когда нажимаю на кнопку 3 вопроса у меня не всегда выдаёт 3 вопроса иногда 2 во проса с пробелом и не видно 1 вопроса что сделать
2)как сделать чтобы он в определенную строку выводил строку из другого мемо

Comment: @OwlGG  1. Видимо, пустая строка добавляется. Нужно, чтобы все строки исходного Memo были заняты вопросами. 2. Свойство Memo Lines - это не что иное, как TStrings. У данного класса есть метод Insert(Index: Integer; const S: string);  где Index - куда вставляете новую строку, а s - сама вставляемая строка

Comment: Тут появился ещё один не большой вопрос, искал информацию про случайное не повторяющееся число, но нашёл только в исполнение, где слишком много кода, не знаешь как реализовать это попроще?